# JS fetch TypeError: Failed To Fetch

Tags: javascript

Whenever i tried to fetch it returned an error TypeError:failed to fetch others solution doesnt to work for me. Here's my code

```
fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => {
     this.JSONData = data;
  })
  .then(() => {
     this.search()
  }) 
  .catch(error => {
     alert(error);
  });
```

Comment: Is this a CORS request?

Comment: @hellojeffhall no its a local request

Comment: What is `url` set to?

Comment: Are you trying to request a resource at `file:` protocol?

Comment: @guest271314 its from a local server using http://localhost not file://

Comment: What does server log for request?

Comment: @guest271314 type error

Comment: What server is being used? There should be more than "type error" logged at a server. What does `resp.status` log? `fetch()` should only reach `.catch()` if a network error occurs. Is your server active and accepting requests? Are you requesting the correct URL? Can you include server type and configuration at text of Question?

Comment: @guest271314 number that keeps on increasing and 200

Comment: What is "number that keeps on increasing"? `200` is a successful response. What is `url` and what is expected result? Are you serving valid `JSON`?

Comment: @guest271314 dont know what that number is, it keeps on incrementing from 0, yes its a valid JSON i've fetch it on my android app successfully

Comment: Not sure how you expect a solution to what you are describing without further details. What exactly is throwing type error? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 nevermind dude i used the XHTMLReq and it turns out successfully

Comment: @guest271314 thanks btw

Answer (score 3):

Is the page reloading before this completes due to async? This can happen in some callbacks that don't return `false`.

In your code, since `resp.json()` is async, the function the fetch is in will return before the fetch completes, but it will have enough time to start the fetch. If this is in an 'onSubmit' for example, if the function returns a non-false value, the page reloads, interrupting your fetch. When the first `then` is encountered (which is async as well), it errors.

To fix,

```
<form onsubmit="myFunctionWithFetch(); return false;">
... or return false in your function and do ...
<form onsubmit="return myFunctionWithFetch();">
```

Comment: This was a missing solution for me!

Comment: and adding  ```function handleClick() ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swagger and you have an ad blocker, make sure to disable the ad blocker. I ran into this testing my ASP.NET Core site with Swashbuckle. Kept getting an instant failure. Disabled the ad-blocker for my dev site and it started working. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before to parse response as JSON, you can check the [HTTP status of the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status):

```js
fetch("https://example.com/page-not-found")
  .then(resp => resp.status === 200 ? resp.json() : alert(resp.status))
  .then(/*...*/)
  .catch(error => alert(error));
```

200 is the HTTP status for [OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200).

Of course, `alert()` is used here for debug/dev purpose only.