# Google Books API - TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax

Still grappling with async... but how come fetch command when placed inside a function is producing a "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

The fetch is working perfectly outside the function when called upon loading.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
    <title>paulywill's Books API Example</title> 
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">   
  </head>  
  <body>
    <h1>Books!</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>    
    <form>
        Search for books: <input id="title" type="text">
        <button class="search-book">Submit</button> 
    </form>
    <div id="content"></div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
document.querySelector('.search-book').addEventListener('click', getBook);
const apiKey = '[myapi]'


function convertHTML(str) {
    newStr = str.replace(/ /g, "+");
    return newStr
}

function getBook() {

    let titleHolder = document.getElementById("title").value;
    console.log("titleHolder: " + titleHolder);
    let title = convertHTML(titleHolder)
    console.log("the title: " + title);
    url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${title}&projection=full&key=${apiKey}`
    console.log("url: " + url);



    fetch(url)        
        .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.items); // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show full error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it resolved. Clue was one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228556/js-fetch-typeerror-failed-to-fetch):

index.html

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>paulywill's Books API Example</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Books!</h1>
    <div id="root"></div>


  <form onsubmit="handleClick(); return false;">
        Search for books: <input id="title" type="text">
        <button class="search-book">Submit</button> 

    </form>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
const apiKey = '[myapi]'


function handleClick() {
    document.querySelector('.search-book').addEventListener('click', getBook);
}


function convertHTML(str) {
    newStr = str.replace(/ /g, "+");
    return newStr
}

function getBook() {

    let titleHolder = document.getElementById("title").value;
    console.log("titleHolder: " + titleHolder);
    let title = convertHTML(titleHolder)
    console.log("the title: " + title);
    url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${title}&projection=full&key=${apiKey}`
    console.log("url: " + url);

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('hello')
            console.log(data) // Prints result from `response.json()` in getRequest
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```